# How can I render different markers with dynamic coordinates into the map, in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to render other markers on the map.
I have a variable in a useState that updates the location of other markers.
I've tried a lot of things but none of them has worked so far so hopefully, someone can help.
Below is my code:

```
  <MapView
        ref={mapView}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        mapType={props.mapType}
        loadingEnabled={true}
        userInterfaceStyle="dark"
      >
        {marker != null && (
          <Marker coordinate={getMarkerCoords()}>
            <Entypo name="location-pin" size={50} color="purple" />
          </Marker>
        )}
        {/* {console.log('check ------------------',trusteeMarker)} */}
        {trusteeMarker !== undefined &&
          trusteeMarker.length > 0 &&
          trusteeMarker !== null &&
          trusteeMarker.map((trustee) => {
            const id = trustee.fullName;
            const trusteeCoords = trustee.currentLocation.location;
            <Marker key={id} coordinate={trusteeCoords}>
              <Entypo name="location-pin" size={80} color="red" />
            </Marker>;
          })}
      </MapView>
```